# SQL query to retrive data from two tables based on below condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table: which role instance  changed time

```
Sr No | TIMESTAMP                         |  RoleInstance   | Id  
1     | 2012-03-14 12:00:00.000           | SLBMRole_IN_1   | 120007  
2     | 2012-03-14 12:01:00.000           | SLBMRole_IN_1   | 120007  
3     | 2012-03-14 12:02:00.000           | SLBMRole_IN_1   | 120007  
4     | 2012-03-14 12:24:00.000           | SLBMRole_IN_0   | 120007  
5     | 2012-03-14 12:25:00.000           | SLBMRole_IN_0   | 120007  
5     | 2012-03-14 12:26:00.000           | SLBMRole_IN_0   | 120007  
6     | 2012-03-14 12:27:00.000           | SLBMRole_IN_1   | 120007  
7     | 2012-03-14 12:28:00.000           | SLBMRole_IN_1   | 120007
```

New table below based on  above table so that get values when changed in RoleInstance happened

```
RoleInstance  | Start time                |  End Time  
SLBMRole_IN_1 |     1st row Time stamp    |  3rd row time stamp(bcz 4th row RoleInstance changed)   
SLBMRole_IN_0 |     4th row time stamp    |   5th row time stamp  
SLBMRole_IN_1 |     6th row time stamp    |   …so on and so forth
```

so basically whenver RoleInstance changed I need to get start time and end time for the same.
Can I get a query to achieve output table as above?

Comment: Minor correction in Title , actually just one table to be converted into another table with different values

Comment: Which rdbms? An analytic function would probably do the trick.

Comment: can we know what kind of sql database? Oracle is good for this

Comment: Actually this is MS SQL Server

Comment: Shouldn't `[Sr No]` be unique?

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,rn = row_number() over (order by timestamp,roleinstance)
into    #temp2
from #temp1
```

I found that srno is repeating hence i have added the row number first

```
select  a.*
from    #temp2 a
where   rn = 1
union all
select  a.*
from    #temp2 a, #temp2 b
where   a.rn+1 = b.rn
and     a.roleinstance <> b.roleinstance
union all
select  a.*
from    #temp2 a, #temp2 b
where   a.rn = b.rn +1
and     a.roleinstance <> b.roleinstance
order by a.rn
```

After adding row number this query will give the required result

Comment: Tried on Sql Server 2005 and pasted here

Comment: I insist :) Carefully look at RoleInstance data

Comment: If you found the problem, Please give the correct one for my understanding. Dont just say that there is a problem.

Comment: [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ddaa7/1) is your query. Compare the results. They DO NOT match.

Comment: @MostyMostacho Thanks for Showing the error. I have missed to see role_1 again in the select query. I have modified it to fit for the user need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here the SrNo is sequential. I say this because SrNo 5 has been duplicated. The following query will do the trick:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (SrNo INT,  DTS DATETIME, RoleInstance VARCHAR(30), Id INT)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
    (1,'2012-03-14 12:00:00.000','SLBMRole_IN_1',120007),
    (2,'2012-03-14 12:01:00.000','SLBMRole_IN_1',120007), 
    (3,'2012-03-14 12:02:00.000','SLBMRole_IN_1',120007),
    (4,'2012-03-14 12:24:00.000','SLBMRole_IN_0',120007),
    (5,'2012-03-14 12:25:00.000','SLBMRole_IN_0',120007),
    (6,'2012-03-14 12:26:00.000','SLBMRole_IN_0',120007),
    (7,'2012-03-14 12:27:00.000','SLBMRole_IN_1',120007),
    (8,'2012-03-14 12:28:00.000','SLBMRole_IN_1',120007)

WITH Logins AS (
    SELECT t2.SrNo, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.SrNo) AS join_no, t2.RoleInstance, t2.DTS, t2.Id
    FROM #temp t2 LEFT JOIN #temp t1 ON t2.SrNo = t1.SrNo +1
    WHERE t1.RoleInstance <> t2.RoleInstance OR t1.RoleInstance IS NULL),
Logouts AS (
    SELECT t1.SrNo, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.SrNo) AS join_no, t1.RoleInstance, t1.DTS, t1.Id
    FROM #temp t1 LEFT JOIN #temp t2 ON t2.SrNo = t1.SrNo +1
    WHERE t1.RoleInstance <> t2.RoleInstance OR t2.RoleInstance IS NULL)
SELECT i.Id, i.RoleInstance, i.SrNo AS InSrNo, i.DTS AS InDTS, o.SrNo AS OutSrNo, o.DTS AS OutDTS
FROM Logins i INNER JOIN Logouts o ON i.join_no = o.join_no
```

The two common table expressions (Logins and Logouts) retrieve the change to a given RoleInstance and the change from a given RoleInstance, respectively. The first does a left join from the second to the first of subsequent records, allowing the first of the two to be null to retrieve the first logon. The second does the reverse, to retrieve the last logoff. These are then joined on the key generated by the ROW_NUMBER() function.